# How to change/format the value displayed in an input field

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an input field set as accepting only integers with a character limit of 6. I would like to when the content is being edited, the displayed value shows in currency format. So if the value is "2", the output is "$2.00" and so on.

My current code is not working.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{

    public InputField Field;

    public void Start ()
    {
        Field.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate{ApplyCurrencyFormat();});
    }

    public void ApplyCurrencyFormat ()
    {
        Field.textComponent.text = "$" + Field.text + ".00";
    }

}
```

I can show `"$" + Field.text + ".00";` in the console but I can't change the output text.

Comment: are you sure the value is always an integer value?

Comment: Why just not use `Field.text = "$" + Field.text + ".00";` ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using this hard coded

```c#
Field.textComponent.text = "$" + Field.text + ".00";
```

which assumes the value is a valid integer value I would rather actually try to parse it and also react to incorrect inputs. The biggest challenge here I guess is that you want to manipulate the same text value you are currently also typing on. This might lead to unexpected behavior from a user perspective.

```c#
private void Start()
{
    Field.onValueChanged.AddListener(ApplyCurrencyFormat);
    Field.text = 0f.ToString("C");
}

private void ApplyCurrencyFormat(string newValue)
{
    // remove whitespace and currency symbols like '$' or '€' depending on the culture
    var str = newValue.Trim().Replace(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol, "");

    // if string is empty use 0.00 $
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    {
        Field.text = 0f.ToString("C");
        return;
    }

    // remove anything that is not a 0-9 '.' or '-'
    Regex.Replace(str, "[^0-9-" + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator + "]", "");

    // check if a . is present
    var match = new Regex(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator, RegexOptions.Compiled).Match(str);

    // get anything before the first .
    var beforeHead = str.Substring(0, str.IndexOf(match.Value, StringComparison.Ordinal));
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(beforeHead) && beforeHead[0] == '-')
    {
        beforeHead = '-' + Regex.Replace(beforeHead, @"[^0-9]", "");
    }
    else
    {
        beforeHead = Regex.Replace(beforeHead, @"[^0-9]", "");
    }
    // get anythin after the .
    var afterHead = Regex.Replace(str.Substring(beforeHead.Length + 1), @"[^0-9]", "");

    // combine to a new float format string
    var validFloatNumber = beforeHead + match.Value + afterHead;

    // if empty again use 0.00 $
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(validFloatNumber))
    {
        Field.text = 0f.ToString("C");
        return;
    }

     // try to parse to float value
    if (float.TryParse(validFloatNumber, out var asFloat))
    {
        var formattedString = asFloat.ToString("C");
        if (Mathf.Approximately(asFloat, 0f) && beforeHead[0] == '-')
        {
            // re add the - in case of 0 otherwise you could never
            // start tying with a -
            formattedString = "-" + formattedString;
        }

        Field.text = formattedString;
    }
    else
    {
        Field.text = 0f.ToString("C");
    }
}
```

[image]

Note this is still not perfect and has some hickups (e.g. when entering the first number) but I hope the idea gets clear.

Comment: I don't understand this. The component is already set as accepting only integers with a character limit of 6. Are you saying I should set it as standard and then apply the numeric restriction plus currency format?

Comment: How exactly did you restrict it to only integers and 6 characters? If this is done directly on the InputField then you most probably also can't add other symbols via code...

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with its a little bit simpler I guess but does the same

```cs
    private void Start()
    {
        inputField.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {ApplyCurrencyFormat();});
    }
    
    //Get only the characters needed to parse
    //Parse the string to float
    //Put the `$` again before the (float) priceValue
    //Set the input field with the correct format
    private void ApplyCurrencyFormat()
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputField.text))
        {
            string priceOnly = inputField.text.Replace("$", "");
            float priceValue = float.Parse(priceOnly);
            string newPrice = $"${priceValue:F}";
            inputField.text = newPrice;
        }
    }
```

Also, you might need to configure your input field's content type like this so users can only enter valid characters.

[content type config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17Wv6.png)